# iOS in app purchase is not working after app has been approved and it's ready to sale

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, itunes

I submitted my app for review and within 16 hours my app got approval and I am able to search it on App Store as well, but in app purchase is not working, but I can test IAP on sandbox environment, and it's the 4th day since my app is on app store but still **IAP is not working** :(.

What I need to do guys?

*Did I miss any step, I mean should I first approve IAP before app release or what?*

please help me.

Comment: Are you able to test using test accounts at your end?

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj yes, I am able to test using sandbox tester id

Comment: itunesconnect.apple.com->manage application-> your application > manage your inApp purchase. please check this

Comment: I uploaded the app, but what is binary to upload?

Comment: your binary has been rejected. now Now go to Manage in-App Purchases and click create New. Give your product Id and type of IAP after creating it shows waiting for review then submit your binary again

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj I forgot to turn on Content hosting while creating IAP, so apple didn't review my IAP, this is the reason. now I turned it on, and now I need to submit my binary again, am I telling right?

Comment: Dear Good to try. Nothing is sure in today Apple. And please let me know

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj ok bro, thank for replying, I'm pushing again now, and I'll tell you further :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205370/discussion-between-vipul-kumar-and-ajjjjjjjj).

Answer (score 3):

Are your IAPs listed as "Approved"?

If so, I have found that doing a simple edit of the description in each IAP helps. Just make an edit, save it, revert to the original and save again. It took up to 8 hours after that but the IAP products then showed up.

IAPs that I did not do this to have still not shown up even 48 hours after release.

Comment: Unbelievable, but it worked. 24 hours nothing showed up, 15 minutes after i did what you suggested it started to load up one by one over an hour. Thanks!